# The for loop in bash runs infinitely when run using slurm

Tags: bash, shell-script, slurm

I have a bash script, called edit.sh that has this block of code:

```
z=$(tail -1 mol-pos-1.xyz | awk '{print $NF}')

echo "before loop: z is $z" >> log

for ((r=0; $(echo "$z>20" | bc -l); r++)); do
    echo "entering loop" >> log

    ll=$(tail -n 1 mol-1.restart)

    if echo "$ll" | grep -q "&END FORCE_EVAL"; then   #check whether mol-1.restart file is written properly
        cp mol-1.restart run.inp
        echo "copied into run.inp" >> log 
        # See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP2K for a description 
        # of CP2K
        cp2k.popt run.inp >> output$r.out 2>> error$r.err &
        wait

        echo "inside if" >> out
    fi

    echo "done running cp2k after $r repeats" >> log
    z=$(tail -1 mol-pos-1.xyz | awk '{print $NF}')
    echo "z is $z" >> log
done

echo "left loop successfully" >> log
```

When I run this script manually on the node, it works well. But when I run it via [SLURM](https://slurm.schedmd.com/overview.html), I end up in an infinite loop with many output$r.out and error$r.err files. The log file also indicates that the loop is running infinitely.

However, all the output$r.out and error$r.err files are completely empty. This is not an environment/path issue because otherwise I should get some error in these files. Also it wouldn't run when manually executed.

I do not understand what is going on.

The slurm script has the following submission command:

```
EXEC="sh edit.sh"
FILE=depo
(mpiexec.hydra -launcher=ssh -genv I_MPI_PIN_PROCESSOR_LIST $(echo "${irun}" | awk '{print $1*1}') -genv OMP_NUM_THREADS 1 -np 1 ${EXEC} ${FILE}.inp >> ${FILE}.out 2>> ${FILE}.err || exit 1) &
```

Why does this one command not run properly?

Comment: Does the log show `z is X` for `X <= 20`?

Comment: Why is the `cp2k.popt` command backgrounded and then immediately waited for? I'm not thoroughly familiar with SLURM but could imagine a batch manager interfering with backgrounded processes, as this is a resource it manages.

Comment: And since `wait`'s exit code isn't checked, then if no child was spawned this will go undetected, which I suppose results in `z` never increasing, and so you'll sit in the loop forever. In fact, the same may happen without the `&` and `wait`. I suggest bailing out the loop if `cp2k.popt` fails (which could e.g. happen because it's not on your `PATH` under SLURM, but is in your `PATH` in your shell on the node).

Comment: Is it possible to base the loop on something else that doesn't require backgrounding?  I tend to agree with @zwets here.  Something else refers to some structure here that will fit in a do while or do until, or even a manual cp?

Comment: A more general advice: always run your submitted scripts with `sh -e` (or `set -o errexit` in the script) so they error out on the first failure, to avoid the wrath of your cluster admins over a runaway process.

Comment: Don't your `echo`s to the log file give you clues? `echo "z is $z"` - does it change? Does it become less than or equal to 20? `echo "done running cp2k after $r repeats" >> log` - does `r` change? `echo "copied into run.inp" >> log` - does that ever get hit? etc....

Comment: Why are you doing `for ((r=0; $(echo "$z>20" | bc -l); r++)); do` instead of just `for ((r=0; z <= 20; r++)); do`?

Comment: Your loop can never end regardless of what environment it's called from - it's exit condition is that `z` becomes less than or equal to 20 but in the loop you do `z=$(tail -1 mol-pos-1.xyz | awk '{print $NF}')` without ever changing the contents of `mol-pos-1.xyz` and so the value of `z` will never change. Unless something you haven't told us about is happening outside of the loop or otherwise behind the scenes to modify that file.

Comment: @zwets I tried using a do while loop and got rid of the wait commands and it still does not do anything. I did check the 'top' on the node and it seems that the cp process gets into state D (which is uninterruptible sleep according to google). There are no running cp2k processes after a while.
The value of z does not change. It would if cp2k ran properly but it does not.

Comment: @EdMorton cp2k takes care of updating the value of z and since the cp2k command does not run properly, yes it never changes in value; hence the infinite loop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the relevant information like that and the answers to my questions about what the log shows so we can help you. Also state what "does not run properly" means. It sounds like you've already narrowed down the problem to something inside the `cp2k.popt` but you haven't shown us what that contains so idk how we can help you further to debug it. FWIW, though, consider the possibility that you might be reading `mol-pos-1.xyz` in the directory you run the command from but `cp2k.popt` is writing to a different version of `mol-pos-1.xyz` in a different directory.

Comment: I'm assuming when you say "cp2k takes care of updating the value of z" you actually mean "cp2k.popt takes care of updating the contents of mol-pos-1.xyz" since there is no way that cp2k[.popt] can update the value of z and even if it could that'd be immediately overwritten by the assignment afterwards outside of the `if...fi`.

Comment: @EdMorton it could in the sense that writes to the xyz file, and thence the assignment to z picks it up.

Comment: @zwets could be, or it could be that the called tool is doing `z=foo` or `echo foo` and the OP thinks that'll change the value of `z` in the calling script. Hopefully they'll reply and update their question to clarify.